# How do I figure out if these two statements imply one another?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

$$x^2>9\Rightarrow |x|>3 \quad \quad |x|>3\Rightarrow x^{ 2 }>9$$

If there is a valid implication between the two, I must show the proof. If not, I must refute it by giving a counter example.

Steps I took:

$x^2>9\Rightarrow |x|>3 $

Assuming: $x^2>9$, I will prove $\left| x \right| >3$

1)  $x^2>9$

2) $x>3$ or $x<-3$

3) So, $x>3$ or $x<-3$ is equivalent to $|x|>3$

4) Therefore, $x^2>9 \Rightarrow |x|>3$

Now, I don't know what to do for: $|x|>3\Rightarrow x^{ 2 }>9$

I don't even know if I am going about this the right way. I would appreciate being guided in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain more clearly why step $2$ holds (e.g., say something to the effect that $1$) is equivalent to $(x-3)(x+3)>0$, which can only happen if both factors have the same sign and proceed from there). For step $4$), compare the inequality in two steps: first by multiplying both sides first by $|x|$, then for the second step, multiply the inequality by $3$.

Comment: What do you mean by what you put for step 4)?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: You have $|x|>3$, which is equivalent to $|x|^2=x^2>3|x|$ by multiplying both sides by $|x|$. Now, instead of multiplying by $|x|$, multiply by $3$ to get $3|x|>3^2=9$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you talking about the proof I already wrote up? Or are you talking about the proof for $\left| x \right| >3\Rightarrow x^2>9$

Comment: Step $2$) is about $x^2>9\Rightarrow|x|>3$. Step $4$) is the converse.

Comment: So, both statements are implied by each other then

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\lvert x\rvert=\sqrt{x^2}$.

*Some details*

As $\lvert x\rvert \ge 0$ for all $x$ and the square function is increasing on $\mathbf R^+$, we have
$$\lvert x\rvert >3 \iff \lvert x\rvert^2 >3^2=9.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $$|x|>3$$ then square both sides and both sides being positive there will be no change in signs $$x^2>9$$